# How to make discord.py bot send messages at random times

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to make my discord bot send a message to a channel at random times here's my code so far:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if (random.randint(0,500) == 42) and (message.author != client.user):
        await message.channel.send("bruh")
    
    elif (random.randint(0,500) == 69) and (message.author != client.user):
        await message.channel.send("good plan")

    elif (random.randint(0,500) == 99) and (message.author != client.user):
        await message.channel.send("awwww hellll nahhhhhhh")

    elif (random.randint(0,500) == 76) and (message.author != client.user):
        await message.channel.send("I think we should see other people...")

    elif (random.randint(0,500) == 25) and (message.author != client.user):
        await message.channel.send("no.")
    
    elif (random.randint(0,500) == 56) and (message.author != client.user):
        await message.channel.send("bad idea")
    
    else:
        return
```

Every time I run the bot with this code, my commands don't work at all. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a on_message event you have to add a `await client.process_commands(message)` at the end of the event
like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if (random.randint(0,500) == 42) and (message.author != client.user):
        await message.channel.send("bruh")
    
    elif (random.randint(0,500) == 69) and (message.author != client.user):
        await message.channel.send("good plan")

    elif (random.randint(0,500) == 99) and (message.author != client.user):
        await message.channel.send("awwww hellll nahhhhhhh")

    elif (random.randint(0,500) == 76) and (message.author != client.user):
        await message.channel.send("I think we should see other people...")

    elif (random.randint(0,500) == 25) and (message.author != client.user):
        await message.channel.send("no.")
    
    elif (random.randint(0,500) == 56) and (message.author != client.user):
        await message.channel.send("bad idea")
    
    else:
        return

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

or you could just use the `@client.listen()` decorator like this:

```py
@client.listen()
async def on_message(message):

    if (random.randint(0,500) == 42) and (message.author != client.user):
        await message.channel.send("bruh")
    
    elif (random.randint(0,500) == 69) and (message.author != client.user):
        await message.channel.send("good plan")

    elif (random.randint(0,500) == 99) and (message.author != client.user):
        await message.channel.send("awwww hellll nahhhhhhh")

    elif (random.randint(0,500) == 76) and (message.author != client.user):
        await message.channel.send("I think we should see other people...")

    elif (random.randint(0,500) == 25) and (message.author != client.user):
        await message.channel.send("no.")
    
    elif (random.randint(0,500) == 56) and (message.author != client.user):
        await message.channel.send("bad idea")
    
    else:
        return
```

if you use the listen() event you dont have to process the commands